# Wifi and bluetooth PHY on SoC

Tags: communication, wireless, soc

I look at different cpu datasheets and a question keep coming back.

On a SoC, and in the case of a PCB design, if I want the maximum throughput between a dumb wifi/BLE chip and my processor (cortex A53), should I look for CPU support of Ethernet MAC (which it has) or is there something else to look at?

What if I want the fastest throughput for both Ethernet (1Gbit/s) and Wifi/BLE on that same SoC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "dumb" wifi/BLE chip will only support the interface protocol it supports. That might be SPI/I2C/Parallel/etc. Unless it also has an Ethernet PHY/networking stack on it, having an Ethernet PHY on your main processor won't help you talk to it any faster. If you want an SoC with Wifi, BLE, and Ethernet, you will just need to find one, if such an SOC exists.

One note though, if you are questioning how to connect various SoCs together for networking, perhaps a custom designed PCB implementing a cortex A53 is not the best project for you. The A-series microprocessors have a lot of requirements in terms of supporting chips, such as flash, ram, and power supplies. Furthermore, a physical Ethernet implementation is not trivial.

Comment: As far as Cortex A is involved, the SoC will do more than just wireless so I need the complexity of this CPU. Do yo know a wireless chip with a PHY interface? It sounds like being a unicorn.

Comment: There are plenty of high speed onboard bus options that would support wifi throughput that you could couple to your main SoC

Comment: Awesome, do you have an example I could use as a starting point please?

Comment: [BCM43460](https://www.broadcom.com/products/Wireless-LAN/802.11-Wireless-LAN-Solutions/BCM43460)